# How do I connect an Outlook calendar to SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

how do I connect an Outlook calendar to SharePoint Online?

I see the option to add a new calendar but I don't know how to get the correct "Outlook Web Access URL" and "Exchange Web Service URL".

[image]

Am I on the right track?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Online Doesn't support Calendar overlay with Exchange web service.

The same question is answered here:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/199097/how-to-find-url-outlook-web-access-url-for-calendar-overlay-with-office-365

Comment: Thanks!  What would you recommend I do as a workaround? Should I just re-create this calendar as a SharePoint calendar?

Comment: I would suggest recreating this calendar as a SharePoint clendar, it is very saey. If you are familiar with Outlook rest API, you could refer to this article: https://codeatwork.wordpress.com/2017/04/16/using-outlook-rest-apis-in-sharepoint-online/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. You can sync using Power Automate. The SharePoint Calendar is a SharePoint list with the name "Calendar". It's a simple PowerAutomate workflow with few steps which you can set up in a few minutes. In case you want to use a Shared Mailbox you can sync the calendar from therein when you share this calendar with your personal mailbox. Then you will see it in Power Automate shown as Calendar to retrieve events from.

Please note: SharePoint Item Action in Power Automate doesn't support all SharePoint List field types, e.g. checkboxes like "All Day Event". Nevertheless you can sync All Day Events which will show up with scheduled time 12pm-12pm.

You can also include SharePoint Calendars as SharePoint Web Part e.g. in a SharePoint Page.